# Resizing screen for iPhone X using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So, there are tens of questions on Stack Overflow referencing about fitting a SpriteKit scene properly on the iPhone X. I could not find anyone however, where there is the same gap.

Is there anyway I can resize the screen just for the iPhone X? Or do I have to create another scene, JUST for the iPhone X to fit the screen?

Here is what I am getting using `.aspectFit`:
[image]

I want to extend that scene towards just under the notch and just above where the screen corner curves are. I see many games which fit perfectly, but have not found a suitable solution.

**Note:** I cannot use `aspectFill` as some parts of the game go out of view.

Any links or answers will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

`resizeFill` is too big, everything gets enlarged

I have tried all 4 options for sizing the screen, but none did the job. Anyone got suggestions?

I feel like the solution is going to be done pragmatically because it will need to be relative to those borders.

Comment: Sounds like you should use `resizeFill`

Comment: @CleverError That makes it way to big - all my sprites are off the screen or enlarged

Comment: You need to change your safe area

Comment: Also, I do not think you understand the point of aspectFill.  Different devices have different aspect ratios, so you are going to have to cut the game graphics somewhere, or suffer from fatty mode with .fill.  Aspect Fit means for games that do not conform to the aspect you design in, you get black bars.  Aspect Fill means that cropping happens. Fill means ignore aspect and stretch graphics however possible to fill all 4 corners, and resize literally resizes your game to match the points of your screen, so you see more game world on a plus device then the SE

Comment: I strongly recommend always designing in a square scene, and having your HUD change for different devices, but if you only plan on doing phones, then design your scene for 39x18, with the extra space being visual fluff so that when it crops to 16x9, only the fluff gets cropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (me and snapbackdev) found a solution, suitable for any phones now or any coming in the future to set the screen to fit the **whole** view, without stretching or empty spaces.

We ended up doing everything programmatically, which made everything work.

In `GameViewController.swift`, this code loads the `GameScene`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        // Load a GameScene with the size of the view
        let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size)

        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)


        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true

    }
}
```

This may also be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead, depending on what you are doing.

The only code needed to setup the scene in `GameScene.swift` is:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Set (0, 0) as the centre of the screen
    scene?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    // Create the frame
    let frameEdge = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    self.physicsBody = frameEdge

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code it will set the Playable Game Area for both the iPhone X and the regular iPhones and then use the gameArea constant to define how far things can move.

```
//MARK: Playable Game Araa
let gameArea: CGRect

override init(size: CGSize) {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
        //iPhone X
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 19.5/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)
    } else {
        let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
        let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
        let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2
        gameArea = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)
    }

    super.init(size: size)
}
```